# ModuleNotFoundError : No module named with locust

Tags: python, locust, modulenotfounderror

When I try to import external library of my project in my locust python file, each time I have the error "ModuleNotFoundError : No module name '...'.

Apparently is not clear but locust is installed and works.
I have a task to make REST API call and it's ok.
But I need to make some action in the **init** method coming from external file of my project

Example :

I want to import the method "generateILogsToken" in my locust file from _Global.py file

***FILE : getWalletInfoLocust.py***

```py
from Phoenix.APIs._Global import generateIlogsToken
from locust import HttpUser, task

class ApiUser(HttpUser):

    def __init__(self, environment):
        print("__init__" + generateIlogsToken())
        super().__init__(environment)


    @task
    def profile(self):
        url = "/restapi/json/v1/resources"
        self.client.get(url, verify=False, headers={'AUTHTOKEN': 'xxxxx'})
```

Error generated with the command locust -f getWalletInfoLocust.py

```
...
    from Phoenix.APIs._Global import generateIlogsToken
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Phoenix'
```

I have this issue for any method imported from external file of my project.
When I'm used behave or other, no isse. It's only with locust.

Thx

Comment: You may need to install the module with `pip install locust` first.

Comment: locust is installed....  if I remove the import of generateIlogsToken, it works.

Comment: Can you show the Phoenix version installed ?

Comment: What is this `Phoenix`package, I can't find it on the web

Comment: Is it possible that you have multiple installations of python and you accidentally installed Locust on one version and Phoenix on another?

Comment: Phoenix is only a folder of my project tree.

Comment: Well it is important to precise this

Comment: genrateILogsToken method is defined in an other python file of my project. When I import this method with pycharm, this one defined all the path to reach this method. It's not a python package coming from PIP, it's a folder of my global project

Comment: Apparently my folder Phoenix should be defined as package. To solve I have added import sys
sys.path.append('../')  and now Phoenix is found by locust

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure, but I think the problem could be related to the fact that you launch your program in a folder that is not the root folder of your project.

Let's say you have a directory tree like this:

```
project_directory
│   getWalletInfoLocust.py  
│   ... 
└───Phoenix 
│   │   ...   
│   └───APIs   
│   │   │   _Global.py
│   │   │   ...
```

When launching the command, python will look for the Phoenix folder from the folder you are launching python from.

To be sure the module is found, you should launch `locust -f getWalletInfoLocust.py` from the directory that I called "project_directory" in my example, otherwise python could not find the module Phoenix.

Alternatively you can add your root directory to sys.path in your file, like this:

```
import sys, os
sys.path.append('path/to/project_directory')
```

Comment: Thanks @Roberto for the explanation. It's very clear

Answer (score 0):

Your Phoenix library is a folder not a package.
So it needs to be imported following this https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importing-a-source-file-directly or this [Importing files from different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Please make sure to add some supporting information to your answer